# Forking Meteor package

Tags: meteor

I find myself needing to fork the spiderable package, but I have a hard time finding any good resources on how to do that with the most recent version of Meteor (0.9.4). Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: [This post](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/local-packages) describes how to download an existing package, modify it, and run it locally.

Comment: Very useful, @DavidWeldon. I wonder why my Google searches never led me to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done exactly that - forked the `http` package into [`http-more`](https://github.com/dandv/meteor-http-more) (unfortunately because the Meteor team [repeatedly refused](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1703) to implement a simple patch I submitted that would allow specifying a proxy).

Check out the [http-more](https://github.com/dandv/meteor-http-more) for the actual implementation. It allows for easily updating your package when the upstream one changes. Essentially the process goes like this:

1. `meteor create --package user:your-package`
2. cd `user\:yuor-package/`
3. `git submodule add https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git`

   At this point you have the entire Meteor repo as a submodule of your package, in the `meteor` directory. You can delete all other directories but `meteor/packages/the-one-you-fork`.
4. Copy somewhere else the files from the upstream package and apply your changes.
5. Generate patch files by running `diff old_file new_file` for the files you've changed.
6. Create a build script that updates the Meteor submodule and generates the final files by applying the patches to source files. Here's [my `build.sh`](https://github.com/dandv/meteor-http-more/blob/master/build.sh):

   ```
   git submodule update --init     # This fetches the submodule repo at the commit...
   cd meteor                       # ...it was when the parent (we) committed.
   git fetch; git checkout master  # Actually update the submodule.
   cd -
   cp meteor/packages/http/{httpcall_server.js,httpcall_tests.js} .
   patch httpcall_server.js httpcall_server.patch
   patch httpcall_tests.js httpcall_tests.patch
   ```
7. Merge the upstream `package.js` into the boilerplate one that `meteor create --package` generated. You'll want the upstream set of dependencies and package files, and you should add/replace [your own GitHub URL](https://github.com/dandv/meteor-http-more/blob/master/package.js#L5), package description, and patched files.

   ```
   Package.describe({
     name: 'dandv:http-more',
     summary: 'Make ninja guru rockstar HTTP calls to remote servers',
     version: '1.0.7_1',  // wrapped package version number - see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/History.md#more-package-version-number-flexibility
     git: 'https://github.com/dandv/meteor-http-more.git'
   });

   // any Npm.depends the upstream has

   Package.onUse(function (api) {
     api.versionsFrom('0.9.0');  // I had to add this
     api.use('underscore');
     api.use('url@1.0.1');  // also had to specify some version of the url package
     api.export('HTTP');
     // original upstream package files
     api.addFiles('meteor/packages/http/httpcall_common.js', ['client', 'server']);
     api.addFiles('meteor/packages/http/httpcall_client.js', 'client');
     api.addFiles('meteor/packages/http/deprecated.js', ['client', 'server']);
     // patched files
     api.addFiles('httpcall_server.js', 'server');  // patched
   });

   Package.on_test(function (api) {
     // ...
     api.use('dandv:http-more', ['client', 'server']);  // your own package

     // same mix of original + patched files
     // ...
   });
   ```
8. Test your package by going to the parent directory and running
   `meteor test-packages user\:your-package/`.
9. If tests pass, change into your directory again and run `meteor publish`, then
   `git commit` and `git push` to publish the package on GitHub.